# Is there a spell that would allow you to transform someone into an object?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, polymorph, objects

Is there any spell in Pathfinder that actually would allow an evil witch to turn an opposing witch into a sentient door knob, or something alike?

It is such a common trope in fantasy that I find it hard that Pathfinder has no mechanic for this, but my searches haven't retrieved any results.

Or should I just "homebrew" a ritual for that? How would you recommend going about that?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] when you get a chance. The first half of your question is a great one and is something this site can definitely answer. The end where you ask for "how do I homebrew this?" isn't something we can answer on stack. If you remove that part this will be a better question. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Comment: Additionally, if the answer to this is "no, you will have to homebrew it." You can bring your homebrew here and [ask a homebrew review question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8121/how-can-i-ask-a-good-homebrew-review-question) which we will be able to answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Polymorph any Object](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph-any-object/)

What you describe is exactly the effects of *Polymorph Any Object*, which says:

> This spell functions like greater polymorph, except that it changes one object or creature into another. You can use this spell to transform all manner of objects and creatures into new forms- you aren’t limited to transforming a living creature into another living form. The duration of the spell depends on how radical a change is made from the original state to its transmuted state.

Then it has a table to calculate the duration based on how *different* the creature's new form is compared to her original form, similar forms (human to frog) will last longer, while completely different forms (human to doorknob) will last only a few hours or minutes.

The spell even gives an example of such duration, *Pebble to human* (20 minutes). A sentient knob would probably be classified either as an [Awakened Construct](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/awaken-construct/) or an [Animated Object](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/animated-object/). But regardless, the choice wouldn't be permanent due to the creature's kingdom changing (animal to vegetable/mineral).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I missread the spell and thought I could only turn creatures to creatures and objects to objects.